# ngif causing page to reload - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display a component when search results are recieved, causing an event emitter to go off, causing `onResultsRecieved()` to execute.

However the page just reloads. So I debugged it, and when the code goes into `onResultsRecieved()`, when it runs `this.results.scroll()` it causes an exception that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scroll' of undefined" and then the page just reloads.

`scroll()` is a method on the results viewchild.

Why is `results` undefined? and why does the exception never show in the console, and instead reload the page?

All code involved:

find-page.component.html

```
<div id="find-page">
   <find-form (onResultsRecieved)="onResultsRecieved($event)"></find-form>
</div>
<results-div #results *ngIf="showResults"></results-div>
```

find-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../shared/navbar.component';
import { FindFormComponent } from '../find-page/find-form.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from '../find-page/results.component';

@Component({
   selector: 'find-page',
   templateUrl: 'app/find-page/find-page.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/find-page/find-page.component.css' ],
   directives: [ FindFormComponent, ResultsComponent ]
})
export class FindPageComponent {
   showResults = false;
    @ViewChild('results') results;

     onResultsRecieved(recieved: boolean) {
        if ( recieved ) {
           this.showResults = true;
           this.results.scroll();
        }else {
           this.showResults = false;
        }
  }
}
```

results.component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'results-div',
   templateUrl: 'app/find-page/results.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/find-page/results.component.css' ]
})
export class ResultsComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   ngAfterViewInit() {
ScrollToAnchor.goToTargetBottom("#results-page");
   }

   scroll() {
      ScrollToAnchor.goToTargetBottom("#results-page");
   }
}

results.component.html:

<div id="results-page"></div>
```

relevant css:

```
#results-page {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 50px; }
```

Comment: well I can tell you that its undefined because the scope is calling scroll prior to that child being available. From what I see, your event is being emitted, due to some functionality within the form component. Could you provide that code? Why its reloading your page.. thoughts but nothing solid. maybe because your calling scroll as a function name and it exists already as a jquery event, its fumbling around with the logic and hits a failsafe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you are using a form, however, I don't see the actual code attached anywhere so this is just going to have to be an educated guess. I was having a very similar problem (which is how I stumbled across this question), and it was fixed very easily.

When you submit a form it will try to take you to wherever the `action` attribute defines, even if there is no action attribute (in which case the form simply reloads the current page). To avoid this, add `onSubmit="return false;"` to your form tag, this will prevent the form from attempting to change the page once the form is submitted.

Hope this helps.