# Angular 2 animation cause page to reload

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have

```
<div class="style1" *ngIf="data" [@slideInLeft]="slideInLeft">
  <form [formGroup]="form1" class="form" *ngIf="form1">
....
     <button [disabled]="this.isUpdating === true" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancelClicked()">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>

import { slideInLeft } from 'ng-animate';

animations: [trigger('slideInLeft', [transition('* => *', useAnimation(slideInLeft))])]
```

When I the form is shown animation work fine. As soon as I click cancel the page reloads.

If I remove animations completely cancel does not reload page.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this? I'm having the same issue but I have my form within a component, the component within a div and the animation on the div. But that cancel still causes a page reload. The only thing my cancel does is toggle a boolean variable.

Comment: This is beacause form is trying to submit in some way :O
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282116/ngif-causing-page-to-reload-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

If you had a stackblitz or something to reproduce the issue, I think I could test my theory. I am guessing it could have something to do with the fact you have the cancel button's type attribute as "submit". That is contradictory of how forms naturally work, the submit button should submit the form, not cancel.

In a plain html  the submit button performs whatever is defined by the action attribute, take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

The first thing I would try is to make the cancel button's type attribute "button", so `<button type="button>` and see if that helps. If you want to handle the submit action via the angular way, you should handle that via `<form (ngSubmit)="takeSomeAction()">`

Answer (score 0):

You button is of type submit, and will thus submit the form.